# C++ Multiple Functions Not Recognized

Tags: c++, arguments

This may be a very simple error, but I made a function called longin_page();

```
int login_page(string username,string password) {
```

Anyways, this is the function header, the function is very long. However, when I call the function in another file(to which the function is defined and referenced), it seems to not recognize the two arguments that I have defined.

```
else if (input1 == "login") {
    get_user_info();
    login_page(file_username, file_password);
}
```

In visual Studio, I get an error saying that the function does not take two arguments. Just in case you wanted to check all my files, they are posted below.

login_page.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "login_page.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "profile_main_menu.h"using namespace std;

string file_username, file_password;

int get_user_info() {

ifstream user_info;
user_info.open("user_info.txt");

if (user_info.is_open()) {
    user_info >> file_username;
    user_info >> file_password;
    cout << "File open" << endl;
    cout << file_username << endl;
    cout << file_password;
}
else {
    cout << "Could not get info fro user_info.txt" << endl;
}
return 0;
}

int login_page(string username,string password) {

string username_input_2;
string password_input_2;

ifstream user_info;
user_info.open("user_info.txt");
string file_username, file_password;
if (user_info.is_open()) {
    get_user_info();
}
else {
    cout << "Error: No username and/or password found on user_info.txt" << endl;
    login_page();
}

cout << "Please enter your username: " << endl;
cin >> username_input_2;

if (username == username_input_2) {
    cout << username_input_2 << " , please enter your password." << endl;
    cin >> password_input_2;

    if (password == file_password) {
        profile_main_menu();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Passwords do not match. Please try again." << endl;
        login_page();
    }
}
else {
    cout << "You do not have an account or you have misspeld your username. Please try again." << endl;
    cout << username_input_2 << endl;
    cout << username << endl;
    login_page();
}
return 0;
```

}

login_page.h:

```
#define LOGIN_PAGE_H
int login_page();
int get_user_info();
```

initial_page_funct.cpp: (This is where I get the error)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "login_page.h"
#include "create_account.h"

using namespace std;

extern string file_username, file_password;

int initial_login() {
string input1;
cout << "Welcome to AgentOS V230.20043." << endl;
Sleep(3000);
cout << "If you do not have an account and wish to create one, enter \"create account\"" << endl;
Sleep(3000);
cout << "If you do have an account, enter \"login\"" << endl;
getline(cin, input1);

if (input1 == "create account") {
    create_account();
}
else if (input1 == "login") {
    get_user_info();
    login_page(file_username, file_password);
}
else {
    cout << "You have not entered a knowned command. Please try again." << endl;
    cout << "This is the command: " << input1 << endl;
    initial_login();
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function declaration in the header is not correct. In login_page.h replace

```
int login_page();
```

with:

```
int login_page(string username,string password);
```

Comment: Wow, sorry to waste your time on such a stupid mistake. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome. It might be tricky to detect these errors with large programs split across several files. Consider accepting the answer if you think it helped.